# Implement Load More function in getItemCount, is it possible?

Tags: android, gridlayoutmanager

I have an adapter and have this code below, my goals are to make some load more function using gridlayoutmanager and get the data from my API URL. My question is, can I use something like if else condition or something on that getItemCount method? If it is possible, how do I implement it on my code? Thanks.

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (eventList==null)?0:eventList.size();       
    }
```

Comment: Did you try the Offical Android Paging library from jetpack? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

Comment: @abstractArrow seems new for me, I'll check it ASAP, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a custom adapter for a RecyclerView

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Object> customRows = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private AdapterActionListener adapterActionListener;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> customRows)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.customRows.addAll(customRows);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    public void refill(ArrayList<Object> customRows)
    {
        this.customRows.clear();
        this.customRows.addAll(customRows);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return Utility.ADAPTER_VIEWTYPE_DEFAULT;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int index) {
        return index + 1;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // ... custom implementation
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        // ... custom implementation
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return customRows.size();
    }

}
```

If you load more data in your activity of fragment, you need to call

```
adapter.refill(data);
```